# Using Resources getResources(); in AppWidget Android

Tags: java, android, random, resources, android-appwidget

I want to use

```
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
Resources res = getResources(); 
myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.xmlString); 
String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
```

When i use the same in an activity it works fine, but if i use in AppWidget class it throws an error in `getResources();` is there any way to use this in AppWidget, basically all i want is to get random xml strings to appWidget, is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With AppWidgetProvider you will get a context object in most calls. Use context.getResources() to retrieve your application resources.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
Resources res = context.getResources();
myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.xmlString); 
String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
```